# Circular Dependency in java- Design

Tags: java, design-patterns, stack-overflow, circular-dependency

How to prevent circular dependency, any design patterns??,otherwise it will cause stack overflow.
I was asked to redesign this.

```
class A {
    static void method(){
        B.method(); 
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        method();
    }
}

class B {
    static void method(){
        A.method(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a similar case to recursion, there has to be some condition to break this call-loop

Answer (score 0):

This is not just circular dependency, this is an infinite [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

You will have to define an exit branch in either `A.method()` or in `B.method()`, for example:

```
class B{
    static void method(){
        if (someCondition) {
            return;
        }
        A.method(); 
    }
}
```

`someCondition` is calculated based on the business problem that is solved with this recursion (you know what it is).

Answer (score 0):

At it's current state this is a will [recur infinitely](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infinite_recursion) since there is no base case defined.

You would need to define atleast one of the methods with a conditional statement in order to make it break out after some state.

```
static void method(condition){
    A.method(); 
}
```